# How to deal with "non-conformable" arrays?

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

How does one do element-wise arithmetic operations with two arrays that are
conformable in the first dimensions but one has also an extra dimension?

Example, multiply array `a` (3 x 3 x 2) by array `b` (3 x 3):

```
a <- array(1:18, dim=c(3,3,2))
b <- diag(3)
```

The following fails because the arrays are non-conformable.

```
> a * b
```

For it to work, you have to cast array `b` into an array with the correct
number of dimensions.

```
> a * array(b, dim=c(3,3,2))
```

This doesn't strike me as being very straightforward and I'm sure there must
be a simpler way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
a * c(b)
```

`c` will strip attributes, which will then allow recycling of `b` as a simple vector and lead to what I believe is your desired outcome:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    5    0
[3,]    0    0    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10    0    0
[2,]    0   14    0
[3,]    0    0   18
```

Comment: Yes, that's the desired outcome.