# R non-conformable arrays

Tags: r

When doing:

```
p0&lt;&ndash;ts0[tt[,1]]*tc0[tt[,2]]
```

I get the following:

```
Error in ts0[tt[, 1]] * tc0[tt[, 2]] : non-conformable arrays
```

The dimension of `ts0[tt[,1]]` is `4147x4147`, while that of `tc0[tt[,2]]` is `4498x4498` which explains. However, I am stumbled as to why they differ in dimensions.

- For the first term `ts0[tt[,1]]` I checked:

  - indices of `ts0`; and
  - range of values of `tt[,1]` (falls within indices of `ts0`, but the dimension of `ts0[tt[,1]]` is *not* as expected)
- For the second term `tc0[tt[,2]]` I checked:

  - indices of `tc0`; and
  - range of values of `tt[,2]` (falls within indices of `tc0`, and the dimension of `tc0[tt[,2]]` is as expected)

Would appreciate if anyone can point me to where the first item above has gone awry.

Details as follows:

```
> dim(ts0[tt[,1]])
[1] 4147
> dim(ts0)
[1] 24
> length(tt[,1])
[1] 4498
> ts0
       0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11       12       13       14       15       16       17 
0.083781 0.082170 0.049946 0.044039 0.046724 0.046187 0.037594 0.055317 0.045650 0.046724 0.046187 0.046724 0.055317 0.046724 0.031149 0.038668 0.035983 0.037594 
      18       19       20       21       22       23 
0.018797 0.002148 0.001611 0.010204 0.027390 0.063373

> as.factor(tt[,1])
......
Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23



-------------------
> dim(tc0[tt[,2]])
[1] 4498
> dim(tc0)
[1] 71
> length(tt[,2])
[1] 4498
> tc0
        1         2         3         4         5         7         9        10        11        13        14        15        16        17        18        19 
0.0644468 0.0010741 0.0005371 0.0096670 0.0016112 0.0026853 0.0005371 0.0005371 0.0166488 0.0042965 0.0037594 0.0354458 0.0069817 0.0064447 0.0021482 0.0026853 
       20        21        22        23        24        25        26        27        28        29        30        31        32        33        34        35 
0.0048335 0.0053706 0.0112782 0.0010741 0.0026853 0.0252417 0.0085929 0.0032223 0.0112782 0.0005371 0.0032223 0.0134264 0.0048335 0.0236305 0.0263158 0.0010741 
       36        37        39        41        42        43        45        46        47        48        49        50        51        52        53        55 
0.0021482 0.0021482 0.0021482 0.0075188 0.0032223 0.0123523 0.0059076 0.0021482 0.0021482 0.0026853 0.0010741 0.0016112 0.0048335 0.0214823 0.1127820 0.0005371 
       56        57        58        59        60        62        63        64        65        67        68        69        70        71        72        74 
0.0096670 0.0069817 0.0026853 0.0032223 0.0080559 0.0085929 0.0053706 0.0005371 0.0316864 0.0021482 0.2626208 0.0005371 0.0112782 0.0016112 0.0032223 0.0923738 
       76        77        78        81        82        83        85 
0.0150376 0.0042965 0.0048335 0.0166488 0.0021482 0.0123523 0.0032223
> summary(tt[,2])
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    1.0    31.0    56.0    49.7    68.0    85.0 
> as.factor(tt[,2])
..............
76 Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 7 9 10 11 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 ... 85
```

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684623/error-in-a-b-y-non-conformable-arrays

Comment: I understand that the error is due to applying operations on arrays that are to be of the same dimensions. eg. nxm array * mxk array. However, I do not understand how the first term (ts0[tt[,1]]) ends up with an unexpected dimension.

Comment: It would be better if you show a small reproducible example using `dput` for others to check the problem.

Comment: You could also try the solution outlined in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396198/how-to-deal-with-non-conformable-arrays?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. tt[,1] contained 0. ts0[0] is not defined. so a offset by 1 was required.